# launching bat file from Izpack installer

Tags: izpack

Hi I am currently developing a installer with Izpack 5.
I want to execute a bat file from the installer. I added the `processPanelSpec.xml` in `install.xml` but the bat file is not starting.

I am geeting this error:

> Launserver.bat not found under izpack-dist/target/staging.

Comment: Can you solve this problem?

Comment: What does the `processPanelSpec.xml` have to do with any .bat file execution? That is done with the `<executable>` tag

Comment: if you could add the content of proccessPanelSpec it could be useful. On the other hand I think the error may happen because the bat file is not in the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

It's late and I'm not familiar with izpack, but at work we have an application deployed with it for which we execute a batch at post install stage with:

```
<pack name="Network Tools" required="yes"
      installGroups="Server upgrade,Server installation">
    <description>Network rules</description>
    <singlefile src="conf/network/firewall.bat"
                target="$INSTALL_PATH/tools/firewall.bat"
                override="true"/>
    <executable
            targetfile="$INSTALL_PATH/tools/firewall.bat"
            stage="postinstall" keep="false">
        <args>
            <arg value="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
        </args>
    </executable>
</pack>
```

File is no more available after install, I assume this is due to `keep="false"`.